# Scipy Handling of Large COO matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix in the form of a scipy `coo_matrix` (size of 5GB). I have to make use of the non-zero entries of the matrix and do some further processing.

What would be the best way to access the elements of the matrix? Should I convert the matrix to other formats or use it as it is? Also, could you please tell me the exact syntax for accessing an element of a `coo_matrix`? I got a bit confused since it doesn't allow slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's build a random COO matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

x = sparse.rand(10000, 10000, format='coo')
```

The non-zero values are found in the `.data` attribute of the matrix, and you can get their corresponding row/column indices using `x.nonzero()`:

```
v = x.data
r, c = x.nonzero()

print np.all(x.todense()[r, c] == v)
# True
```

With a COO matrix it's possible to index a single row or column (as a sparse vector) using the `getrow()`/`getcol()` methods. If you want to do slicing or fancy indexing of particular elements then you need to convert it to another format such as `lil_matrix`, for example using the `.tolil()` method.

You should really read the [`scipy.sparse` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) for more information about the features of the different sparse array formats - the appropriate choice of format really depends on what you plan on doing with your array.